# What does $x_{1:n}$ notation mean?

Tags: notation

Notation in my book, *Introduction to Probability and Mathematical Statistics* by Bain and Engelhardt, is $x_{1:n}$ and $x_{n:n}$. For example, see Example 10.2.3 (page 340). [Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke1gL.png)

Can anybody tell me what this denotes?

Comment: You might need to include more detail. Usually, notations don't have a unique meaning.

Comment: Most likely it stands for $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n$

Comment: Looks like an shorthand for indexing, as @Shailesh wrote.

Comment: Notation in *which* book?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very specific. I believe @Shailesh is correct. Thanks

Comment: Tell us what book? Help people help you.

Comment: It is from Introduction to Probability and Mathematical Statistics by Bain and Engelhardt

Comment: You should also have given the page where it is used or (better) introduced, and shared an example of how it appears in context.

Comment: It could also mean the first element (minimum) of order statistics of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this might denote a sequence of numbers $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, ..., $x_{n}$